# Browser - USB interface.

Tags: plugins, browser, usb

I have a Garmin 800 GPS device. To upload data from it, all I need to to is plug it into a USB port & install a browser plugin and I can browse the device from a web page.

What is it that facilitates this? In a very broad question, where should I go/what should I be searching for to learn more about it and potentially implement it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The browser is NOT going to connect to your USB device, nor it is going to know anything about the type of connection you are using. I don't have Garmin 800 GPS myself, but I can tell you that technically (most likely) the actual connection will be handled by your OS and you will be browsing the files on USB-connected HDD device or (less likely) the Garmin 800 GPS will be running an http server that you will be accessing via the browser.

The details of the URL that you are using to access the GPS data will give you a clue to the access type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Germann. Ater a little digging, I've found this: http://developer.garmin.com/web-device/garmin-communicator-plugin/ does that help at all?